# Create dict from txt files in multiple directories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series of directories in a structure somewhat like:

E.G.

```
basepath>abcd
basepath>abcd>aba
basepath>abcd>aba>abb
basepath>abcd>aba
basepath>abcd>abd
basepath>abcd>abd>add
```

Other than basepath, directory names are randomly generated strings. There are a few hundred different directories.

Within every directory I have 2 files, 'body.txt' and 'timestamp.txt'. As an end goal I'd like to have collected every body within a common range of time, such as splitting every body into 1 hour intervals. The data in timestamp.txt is a integer of seconds.

I'm imagining the first challenge will be to get a list of every directory and subdirectory. Can anyone suggest what I can use to get a list of subdirectories under `basepath`?

Then I need a way to sort and organise this data. I know that Pandas has a way that I can split data by date, that is possibly my best option that I know of. If anyone had any suggestion of a different method I could do that I'd love to hear it.

As an example of how I'd organise + split the data:

```
Timestamp(s)        Body
300                  a
301                  b
304                  c
306                  d
301                  e
304                  f
301                  g
306                  h
308                  i
307                  j

Split as an interval of 2 secs

Timestamp(s)        Body
300                  a
301                  b
301                  e
301                  g

304                  c
304                  f

306                  d
306                  h

307                  j
308                  i
```

Comment: For the first problem you can use python `os` module `os.walk`. Seconds problem is not clear to me what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Epsi95 Thanks. I've added an simplified example of how I'd like to split up the data, as I'm aware I didn't explain it too clearly.

Comment: `Timestamp` is in timestamp.txt and `Body` is in body.txt?

Comment: @Epsi95 That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read files you can scan all the subfolders in your base path, looking for files named `body.txt` or `timestamp.txt`. You can use `os.walk`: it recursively traverses the tree having the base path as root node and, at each iteration, it returns the path of the current folder, a list with the names of the folders it contains, and a list of the files in that folder; `os.walk` explores all the subfolders in the basepath. Then, you can convert each `timestamp.txt` or `body.txt` in a `pandas` `DataFrame` and concatenate them together. I suppose that both files have one sample per line, something like this:

```sh
timestamp.txt

1609004661.419179
1609004662.419179
1609004663.419179
1609004664.419179
```

```sh
body.txt

b
g
b
g
j
```

As you noticed, timestamps are assumed to be in [UNIX timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format.

Here is an example of the code:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

BASEPATH = 'your base path'
BODY_NAME = 'body.txt'
TIMESTAMP_NAME = 'timestamp.txt'

bds = []  # list to collect data in 'body.txt' files
ts = []
for parent_dir, folders, files in os.walk(BASEPATH):
    print(parent_dir, folders, files)
    try:
        bds.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(parent_dir, BODY_NAME), header=None, names=['body']))
        ts.append(
            pd.read_csv(os.path.join(parent_dir, TIMESTAMP_NAME), header=None, names=['timestamp'],
                        converters={'timestamp': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(float(x), unit='s')})
        )
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass  # handle folders without one of the two files
data = pd.concat((pd.concat(ts, axis=0), pd.concat(bds, axis=0)), axis=1).sort_values('timestamp').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Running the previous code, `data` is something like this:

```sh
                       timestamp body
0  2020-12-26 17:44:21.419178963    b
1  2020-12-26 17:44:21.419178963    c
2  2020-12-26 17:44:21.421484947    f
3  2020-12-26 17:44:21.421484947    e
4  2020-12-26 17:44:21.421484947    j
5  2020-12-26 17:44:22.419178963    f
6  2020-12-26 17:44:22.419178963    g
7  2020-12-26 17:44:22.421484947    f
8  2020-12-26 17:44:22.421484947    f
9  2020-12-26 17:44:22.421484947    i
10 2020-12-26 17:44:23.419178963    k
11 2020-12-26 17:44:23.419178963    b
12 2020-12-26 17:44:23.421484947    b
13 2020-12-26 17:44:23.421484947    d
14 2020-12-26 17:44:23.421484947    i
```

For the second part of your question, you can collect data in an interval of two seconds in different `DataFrame`s using `resample` (after making `timestamp` the index of the `DataFrame`):

```py
data.set_index('timestamp', drop=True, inplace=True)
resampled = data.resample('2s')
df_2sec = {}
for i, (timestamp, df) in enumerate(resampled):
    df_2sec[i] = df
```

Here the first two of these `DataFrame`s (`df_2sec[0]` and `df_2sec[1]`):

```sh
                              body
timestamp                         
2020-12-26 17:44:21.419178963    b
2020-12-26 17:44:21.419178963    c
2020-12-26 17:44:21.421484947    f
2020-12-26 17:44:21.421484947    e
2020-12-26 17:44:21.421484947    j
2020-12-26 17:44:22.419178963    f
2020-12-26 17:44:22.419178963    g
2020-12-26 17:44:22.421484947    f
2020-12-26 17:44:22.421484947    f
2020-12-26 17:44:22.421484947    i
                              body
timestamp                         
2020-12-26 17:44:23.419178963    k
2020-12-26 17:44:23.419178963    b
2020-12-26 17:44:23.421484947    b
2020-12-26 17:44:23.421484947    d
2020-12-26 17:44:23.421484947    i
2020-12-26 17:44:24.419178963    g
2020-12-26 17:44:24.419178963    d
2020-12-26 17:44:24.421484947    i
2020-12-26 17:44:24.421484947    e
2020-12-26 17:44:24.421484947    i
```

You can change the starting timestamp of the `resample` (I chose the first timestamp in the `DataFrame`, using the `start` value for `origin` argument): take a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) for more info.

If you prefer, you can convert each `DataFrame` to a `dict`, changing `df_2sec[i] = df` to `df_2sec[i] = df.to_dict()`.

*NOTE*:
I used the following code to create the structure of your folder, in case you want to reproduce data from my answer.

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd


BASEPATH = 'your base path'
BODY_NAME = 'body.txt'
TIMESTAMP_NAME = 'timestamp.txt'

BODIES = 'abcdefghijk'
FOLDER = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def create_rnd_folder(basepath, level=2, timestamp=None):
    """Generate two-levels random directories"""
    if level == 0:
        n_samples = np.random.randint(1, 100)
        with open(os.path.join(basepath, TIMESTAMP_NAME), 'w') as f:
            for i in range(n_samples):
                f.write(f'{timestamp + i}\n')

        with open(os.path.join(basepath, BODY_NAME), 'w') as f:
            for s in np.random.choice(list(BODIES), size=n_samples):
                f.write(f'{s}\n')
    else:
        new_folders = [np.random.choice(list(FOLDER), size=3 + level) for _ in range(np.random.randint(2, 4))]
        for nf in map(''.join, new_folders):
            new_folder = os.path.join(basepath, nf)
            os.makedirs(new_folder, exist_ok=True)
            _create_rnd_folder(
                new_folder, level=level - 1,
                timestamp=(datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).timestamp() if level == 2 else timestamp
            )


os.makedirs(BASEPATH, exist_ok=False)
create_rnd_folder(BASEPATH, level=2, timestamp=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# I hope you are able to create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([[300 ,'a'],
[301 ,'b'],
[304 ,'c'],
[306 ,'d'],
[301 ,'e'],
[304 ,'f'],
[301 ,'g'],
[306 ,'h'],
[308 ,'i'],
[307 ,'j']], columns=['Timestamp(s)', 'Body'])

# Now that you have the DataFrame
df.sort_values(by=['Timestamp(s)'], inplace=True)

df.sort_values(by=['Timestamp(s)'], inplace=True)
df['group_id'] = df['Timestamp(s)'].apply(lambda x: x-x%2)
        
for group_name, group in df.groupby(['group_id']):
    print(group)
```

output

```
0           300    a       300
1           301    b       300
4           301    e       300
6           301    g       300

2           304    c       304
5           304    f       304

3           306    d       306
7           306    h       306
9           307    j       306

8           308    i       308
```